# PHP application moving to Docker failed to connect on AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker

I have an application that is currently running successfully in the following configuration:

- nginx platform
- PHP 7.0
- redis driver
- pdo driver

running under an ec2 instance ubuntu, connecting to an rds instance to a mysql 5.6.

My goal is to start slowly migrating the application to self contained docker component for php.

here is the docker file

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        mysql-client \
        libxslt1-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt mysqli xsl pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql \
  && pecl install -o -f redis \
  && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
  && echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini \
  && apt-get install -y git wget libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libicu-dev g++ make cmake libuv-dev libgmp-dev uuid-dev \
```

Issue:
When I run the app - I am getting a connection refused.

Verification:

- I have installed mysql-cli within the docker, and used the username
  and password. I have connected successfully.
- I have created a simple php file, initializing a pdo connection with the same username and password. I have connected successfully.

The code is tested via travis under a container environment (non-sudo) successfully with mysql running.

Someone pointed out that I had = instead of : as part of my dsn, I have changed that without success.

I have ran out of ideas?

Comment: Could it be a problem with security groups?

Comment: @R0MANARMY on the ec2 to allow the docker to function? when i go into the docker it can run a php file which has the PDO setup and connect to the mysql so AWS security looks fine, and the docker group itself looks fine also unless you can tell me what i should be looking for that is different

Comment: That was just a shot in the dark, I've had connection timeouts because security groups weren't letting traffic through.

Comment: Given all of this (Your test file is working, mysql-cli is working), it sounds like the networking is setup just fine. I'd guess the application isn't correctly picking up the right hostname or port to use for RDS.  Try having the app echo out what connection details it's using to connect.

Comment: @fideloper thanks for looking into this and giving me your opinion - Ill re-check the app.

Comment: On the EC2, in the container, is the DB DSN string available?